# Thymeleaf- spring error : The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have 3 Html files, I tried all of them in IntelliJ's 3 of them worked well. But when I tried in
localhost the file I mentioned below is giving an error, an error on the title.

```
package com.example.thymeleaf;

public class InputText {
    private String mainText;
    private String comFunc;
    private String funcName;
    private String expByText;
    private Integer expByLimit;

    public String getMainText() {
        return mainText;
    }

    public void setMainText(String mainText) {
        this.mainText = mainText;
    }

    public String getComFunc() {
        return comFunc;
    }

    public void setComFunc(String comFunc) {
        this.comFunc = comFunc;
    }

    public String getFuncName() {
        return funcName;
    }

    public void setFuncName(String funcName) {
        this.funcName = funcName;
    }

    public String getExpByText() {
        return expByText;
    }

    public void setExpByText(String expByText) {
        this.expByText = expByText;
    }

    public Integer getExpByLimit() {
        return expByLimit;
    }

    public void setExpByLimit(Integer expByLimit) {
        this.expByLimit = expByLimit;
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
package com.example.thymeleaf;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/inputForm")
    public String showForm(Model model) {
        InputText inputText = new InputText();
        model.addAttribute("inputText", inputText);
        return "inputForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/inputForm")
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("inputText") InputText inputText){
        System.out.println(inputText);
        return "inputformSuccess";
    }
}
```

**Application class**

```
package com.example.thymeleaf;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ThymeleafApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ThymeleafApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**This is the html file which is not working** mainText, comFunc, funcName firstly have * tag but it gave error so i changed to $ but it still not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xlmns : th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> User Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>User Registration</h1>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/inputform}" th:object="${inputText}" method="post">
            <label> Main Text:</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="${mainText}" /><br/>

            <label> Combine Function: </label>
            <input type="text" th:field="${comFunc}" /><br/>

            <label> Function Name: </label>
            <input type="text" th:field="${funcName}">
        </form>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need `*` not `$`. Fix that error or add that error to your question.

Comment: Can not resolve 'comFunc' errors in IntelliJ but it runs well and then gave the same error in localhost

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the stacktrace you have. Is it the erro in Intellij (validation) or while running the application?